# Send email with attachment , that attachement will be uploaded in the same FORM where from the mail gets triggered

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

Send email with attachment,that attachement will be uploaded in the same FORM where from the mail gets triggered.

**BACKGROUND:** 
i.e. I have an FORM that will take name, address etc details from a FROM. After filling the details user would be allowed to a browse and upload an attachment. Onclicking the Upload button the file will get uploaded to the server.

After doing all of the above action when the users clicks on SUBMIT button in this FROM, it should trigger a email with all the details entered in  the FORM and With the uploaded file attached in it.

Now, the problem I am facing is : when I click on UPLOAD button, the file is getting uploaed but all the inputs entered gets disappeared.

Any resolution around this will be appreciated.
N.B: We are not using any free ware like for mail functioanlity. Mail is send by a vbscript function.

below is the logic how i/p fields values are getting captured:

```
ssr_imo = sql_ship_friendly(request.form("ssr_imo"),10)
ssr_ship_name = sql_ship_friendly(request.form("ssr_ship_name"),100)
ssr_ins_nr = sql_ship_friendly(request.form("ssr_ins_nr"),20)
ssr_ins_date = sql_date_friendly(request.form("ssr_ins_date"),30)
port_name = sql_ship_friendly(request.form("port_name"),50)
ssr_port_id = sql_ship_friendly(request.form("ssr_port_id"),20)
opStat = sql_ship_friendly(request.form("opStat"),20)

subEmail = sql_ship_friendly(request.Form("ssr_sub_email"),200)
subName = sql_ship_friendly(request.Form("ssr_sub_name"),70)

ssr_q2 = validate_q_ssr(request.form("ssr_q2"))
ssr_q3 = validate_q_ssr(request.form("ssr_q3"))
debugNote "<b> TEST = </b>" & ssr_q3
ssr_q4 = validate_q_ssr(request.form("ssr_q4"))
ssr_q5 = validate_q_ssr(request.form("ssr_q5"))
ssr_q6 = validate_q_ssr(request.form("ssr_q6"))
ssr_q7 = validate_q_ssr(request.form("ssr_q7"))
ssr_q8 = validate_q_ssr(request.form("ssr_q8"))
ssr_q9 = validate_q_ssr(request.form("ssr_q9"))
ssr_q10 = validate_q_ssr(request.form("ssr_q10"))
ssr_q11 = validate_q_ssr(request.form("ssr_q11"))
ssr_q12 = validate_q_ssr(request.form("ssr_q12"))
ssr_q13 = validate_q_ssr(request.form("ssr_q13"))
ssr_qa = validate_q_ssr(request.form("ssr_qa"))
ssr_qb = validate_q_ssr(request.form("ssr_qb"))
```

Comment: I have code files but 4 asp pages are there..not sure how to upload those all for your reference

Comment: What upload component or script are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Once you change your form enctype to "multipart/form-data" you can no longer retrieve input values with Request or Request.Form, you have to use the method/function that is part of the upload component or script that you are using.

For example:

- In Persit's AspUpload you use **obj.Form("inputName")** In ChestySoft's
- csASPUpload you use **obj.Value("inputName")**

(In both cases **obj** is the name of your upload component object instance and **inputName** is the name of your form element)

Edit: Using the ASP class you are using for uploading you should use Uploader.Form instead of Request.Form to retrieve input values.

Comment: Hi John, thank for ur view.I am using Vbscript class codes to upload..browse and save it to server.

Comment: Can you show how you are trying to get the value sof the INPUTs, and also show your upload class code?

Comment: This is the way INPUTS are taken in the code:
'<div class="portDetailsItem">
<label for="port_name"  class="lbl30">Inspection Port</label>
<input type="text" id="port_name" name="port_name" value="<%=sesh_port_name%>" onkeyup="searchForPortsFromNames(); return false;" onkeypress="return cancelEnter(event);" autocomplete="off" disabled />

Comment: I would need to see the code that retrieves the values of the INPUTs and also the Upload class code you are using.

Comment: this is upload.asp that is called when clicking upload button from ssr.asp page.ssr.asp page has the UI controls..upload.asp in turns calls the uploadexample.asp..Since I am not able to paste entire code due to character limit here..pasting some parts of it

Comment: .<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<%Option Explicit%>
<!-- #include file="uploadexmple.asp" -->
<%
Dim Uploader, File, FileSys, FilePath,Path,RootPath,scriptPath,env,fo,x,mailbody,shipName,ssr_ship_name,ssr_ins_nr,ssr_imo,subEmail,subName
Set Uploader = New FileUploader
env = Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME")
Uploader.Upload()
If Uploader.Files.Count = 0 Then
    Response.Write "File(s) not uploaded."
Else    For Each File In Uploader.Files.Items
 Session("File")=File.FileName

Comment: And how are you getting the values of your inputs? Are you using Request("inputName") or Request.Form("inputName")? You should possibly be using Uploader.Form("inputName")? You can post more of your code in your original question by editing it, instead of pasting it in to a comment.

Comment: In your Uploadexample.asp script try changing all the request.form to Uploader.Form

Comment: Hi John..I could not find any requset.form in the Uploadexample.asp..this code file is pasted below..could you pls specify where I need to make change.

Comment: Sorry, I meant addSSR.asp - in all the lines like this one - ssr_imo = sql_ship_friendly(request.form("ssr_imo"),10) - change the request.form to Uploader.Form

Comment: hi John..tried bt no luck..is thr any way 2 assign 2diff html form action with a single form tag?? so that one action will be addSSR.asp and other will be upload.asp???   OR alternatively ...in any way can I copy and paste the whole code of upload.asp and uploadexample.asp into the same addSSR.asp file??? so that I can avoid two diff form actions??..I tried this way but finding error since upload.asp file has vbscript class code..

Comment: I think you need to combine the code from addSSR.asp and upload.asp in to one page. You cant submit to two pages.

Comment: Hi..John..tried this way also..but getting an error saying "<%@ Language=VBScript %> shud be the 1st line in the code" even though I am using this line as the 1st line in the combined code..

Comment: Make sure you only have the @Language line once as the first line. If not you will have to show your code.